# Error when installing Azure AD Provisioning Agent

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim

I tried to install the Azure AD Provisioning agent listed here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=103664 but I got the error "Installation requires Windows Server 2012 R2 or higher." I tried to install this on my local machine that runs Windows 10. Is it possible to install the agent on a machine just running windows 10 or 11. The doc here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/on-premises-scim-provisioning doesn't mention any pre-requisites.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a product manager at Microsoft on the Azure Active Directory/Entra team. The error here is accurate - this agent requires that it be installed on a Windows Server OS version 2012 R2 or later. We'll get the omission in the documentation regarding this corrected. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.